# WD-Mobile barcode scanner via serial port

Tags: java, android, mobile, windev

Recently we got an android tablet with an in-built barcode scanner, when we asked for the SDK, the provider just sent us the android serialport api.

Has anyone implemented the android serialport api with an in-built barcode scanner in windev mobile?

I honestly do not know where to start with this...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you able to tell, who's your vendor and if the api is open source or avaible in public?

Comment: Our vendor is Anwda, when we asked for the SDK they only sent the open source api http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending what u want. If u have a android Windows Mobile device that has a bultin scanner u should use the comport to communicate. 
If u want to use the camera i suggest u use one of the existing apps for scanning barcodes. (U can launch them using a intent). The downside is u need to install a second application.

More on launching a other app in WD http://www.mysnip.de/forum-archiv/thema-27131-126196/WM16+Android+-+Open+App+from+an+App+SOLVED.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, The device does have a built in scanner, however I'm too much of a newb on java, can't seem to get the scanner to work, much less port it to windev mobile.

Comment: Depending on your requirements i would recommend using a 3th party application to do the scanning for u. I use this application for barcode scanning https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android (have not implemented it in another application). But given this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821950/android-barcode-scanner-using-zxing i think it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however upon trying the thirdparty app, i realize that the tablet's camera sucks so much... the barcode scanner app can't detect any barcodes at all. has anyone gotten any of the barcode apps to use an integrated barcode scanner?

Comment: I read your first comment wrong, it does have a real barcode scanner. Can use link to the device you're using? In that case i think it's just a comport accessible in your device.
Could u try a comport application on the market like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nz.co.cloudstore.serialbot and see if i can connect it to a local RS232 port and get any output when u scan a barcode.

Comment: Link to the device: http://malinda.sell.sxprice.org.cn/pz5afd471-an-pc5-fingerprint-handheld-terminal-with-phone-calling-function.html

Tried using that app, it can't find the barcode scanner. Gonna check out other apps, maybe one will work.